# How to configure dnsmasq to use /etc/hosts instead of "dhcp-host"?

Tags: centos, dhcp, dnsmasq

I have been able to configure static ip for specific client in /etc/dnsmasq.conf by using "dhcp-host":

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/cosmic/en/man8/dnsmasq.8.html

I would like to use /etc/hosts instead, so I have only one place to maintain for both the DNS and the DHCP.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your "one place" is the `dnsmasq.conf` file.

```
# sticky IP address
dhcp-host=11:22:33:44,192.168.1.1,stickybox

# A record (like /etc/hosts)
host-record=namedbox,192.168.1.2
```

Comment: It is still useful to have same names in /etc/hosts, so that resolving will work even if dnsmasq is down.

Answer (score 1):

According to the manpage, dnsmasq actually reads /etc/hosts for exactly that purpose.
Just remove that dhcp-host line, and add a

```
192.168.1.1 stickybox
```

line to `/etc/hosts`. If you want to add the MAC address as well, add

```
11:22:33:44:55 192.168.1.1
```

to `/etc/ethers` and enable `read-ethers` in dnsmasq.conf.

See http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html

Comment: It's worth nothing that this still requires a `dhcp-host` entry for the hostname, however it can simply be `dhcp-host=stickybox`, which will cause DNSMASQ to resort to `/etc/hosts` for the IP. See the [`dhcp-host`](http://www.thekelleys.org.uk/dnsmasq/docs/dnsmasq-man.html) section of the manpage for more information.

Comment: `dhcp-host` is not required with `read-ethers`, given that entries are equivalent to using `dhcp-host` according to the man page entry for `read-ethers`. This works in my experience. Adding `expand-hosts` to add the local domain to entries from `/etc/hosts` can be useful, though.